# Can I read and parse Excel sheets through php w/o read.php?

Tags: php, excel

I need to read many excel sheets and for that, i'm using php.
My question is where can I get this read.php and where should I save it?
also, where should I put my excel sheets ? I never saw path for excel sheets given in codes on the web.

Comment: Have you consulted the PHP manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: I need the commands to read the excel sheets, but at the fist line of the most codes, I see read.php that I don't know about.

Comment: Where did you get your original code from, and do you have any code to show?

Comment: Are you talking about `SpreadsheetReader` by any chance from Google code? http://code.google.com/p/php-spreadsheetreader/source/browse/CSV/SpreadsheetReader_CSV.php?r=26

Comment: this is there too! is it a famous code from google? I found many code using $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]

Comment: that's a easy command, but that the beginning I always see read.php !

Comment: @fred, there are bunch of codes out there, and my question is that most of them have read.php!

Comment: It depends what you want to output/use it as. Do you have an example of what you want to achieve? This will help me/us better to understand fully.

Comment: I see, actually, if I can read it and have in a variable, then I can do whatever I want, like saving it into my database.

Comment: like reading row by row and putting it into my db row by row

Comment: To somewhat answer your question, the short answer is `NO`, you don't need `read.php` exclusively. You can output using the built-in CSV function in PHP. Try to Google what you just said `read CSV row by row insert to db PHP database`

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553875/how-to-handle-large-csv-files-to-insert-into-mysql

Comment: Google results: https://www.google.ca/search?q=%28this%29%20php%20FUnction&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=read+CSV+row+by+row+insert+into+db+PHP+database&oq=read+CSV+row+by+row+insert+into+db+PHP+database&gs_l=serp.3...181532.181532.8.181924.1.1.0.0.0.0.192.192.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.serp.abrfSzL5AT4&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.aWc&fp=aeb02e4a03929597&biw=1024&bih=551

Comment: Another result on SO which may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498912/error-while-importing-excel-file-into-database

Comment: Now my guess is that `read.php` file must be the code shown on http://code.google.com/p/php-spreadsheetreader/source/browse/CSV/SpreadsheetReader_CSV.php?r=26 you could try saving it as read.php to see what it will result in.

Comment: Question: By database, are you talking about a flatfile (text-based) or MySQLi type?

Answer (score 2):

PHPExcel is a free full-featured PHP library for reading and writing Excel spreadsheets (xls & xlsx too).

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Almost anything can be done with this, that an average user does with Excel, but it's usage needs OOP skills and some higher level practice at PHP.

Comment: It's a good one to use and I have used it before, however this may prove to be slightly over the level of experience I sense in getting from the person asking the question. Good choice though ;-) cheers

Comment: Thanks Kenez, I see a command like 
$data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$j]
that if I can use it, that would be helpful alot for me, I just don't know how to use it. your file is too much for my work. thanks though :)